# Run sync script on AWS ec2 triggered by write

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an ec2 instance running and have setup it up where it takes SFTP writes (I have to use SFTP unfortunately so I am aware of better solutions but I can't use them).  I have an s3 bucket mounted but I ran into an issue with allowing SFTP writes directly into the bucket.  My work around is to run

```
aws s3 sync <directory> s3://<s3-bucket-name>/
```

And this works.  My problem I don't know how to run this script automatically, I would prefer to run it whenever there is a write to a specified directory but I will settle for it running on regular intervals.

So essentially my question is "How do I fire a script automatically in a ec2 aws instance running linux"

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `inotifywait` for file watcher or use `cronjob` to kick-off your `S3 Sync` script at regular interval.